# GCP Network Loadbalancer doesn't forward traffic to Backend

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcp-load-balancer

I have a couple of machines behind a GCP Network Loadbalancer. I set up the firewall rules as indicated in the docs allowing health check from these specified addresses:

```
"35.191.0.0/16",
"209.85.152.0/22",
"209.85.204.0/22"
```

The issue is that I can't access the backend machines through the LB public address even though I configured properly the forwarding rules with the correct ports, and when I open 0.0.0.0/0 to the backend machines I access the backend without any issue.

The thing is I don't want to open connection to all clients ( 0.0.0.0/0). Is there a way to make connections to backend only allowed from the LoadBalancer as I was expecting?

Comment: What's type of load balancer do you use? Which port/protocol are you using? Are you sure that your VM serve the correct port/protocols on them?

Comment: The load balancer is of the type TCP Network LB, and the VMs serve the correct port/protocol and the proof is when I add the 0.0.0.0/0 firewall rule I can get the access.

Comment: Do you have a green healthcheck with your current firewall rule? If so you also have to authorize your IP to access the VMs

Comment: Yes health check is green with current rule, but why should authorizing my IPs to access the VMs since I'm not accessing them directly but through the LB? or at least this is what I think.

Answer (score 2):

TCP load balancer is a port forwarder, not a proxy. If it was a proxy, you should have to authorize the load balancer IP.

Look at the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/firewall-rules) about a proxy LB

[image]

For your network load balancer (port forwarding)

[image]

Comment: Does that mean it's not balancing the traffic?

Comment: Yes, it's balancing traffic between the VMs, but it not proxy the communication